# Python: general iterator or pure function for testing any condition across list

Tags: python, lambda, iterator

I would like to have a function `AllTrue` that takes three arguments:

- List: a list of values
- Function: a function to apply to all values
- Condition: something to test against the function's output

and return a boolean of whether or not all values in the list match the criteria.

I can get this to work for basic conditions as follows:

```
def AllTrue(List, Function = "Boolean", Condition = True):
  flag = True
  condition = Condition
  if Function == "Boolean"
    for element in List:
      if element != condition:
        flag = False
        break
  else:
    Map = map(Function, List)
    for m in Map:
      if m != condition:
        flag = False
        break
  return flag
```

Since python doesn't have  function meant for explicitly returning if something is True, I just make the default "Boolean". One could clean this up by defining `TrueQ` to return True if an element is True and then just mapping `TrueQ` on the `List`.

The else handles queries like:

```
l = [[0,1], [2,3,4,5], [6,7], [8,9],[10]]
AllTrue(l, len, 2)
#False
```

testing if all elements in the list are of length 2. However, it can't handle more complex conditions like `>`/`<` or compound conditions like `len > 2 and element[0] == 15`

How can one do this?

---

Cleaned up version

```
def TrueQ(item):
  return item == True


def AllTrue(List, Function = TrueQ, Condition = True):
  flag = True
  condition = Condition
  Map = map(Function, List)
  for m in Map:
    if m != condition:
      flag = False
      break
  return flag
```

and then just call `AllTrue(List,TrueQ)`

Comment: Am I missing something obvious? Why not just `all(map(lambda x: x == condition, iterable))`? Also, please use `snake_case` for functions and `variable_names`.

Comment: `all(map(lambda sub:len(sub) == 2,l))`

Comment: Or perhaps more idiomatically, use generator expressions: `all(len(sub) = 2 for sub in l)`

Comment: How could you make what you wrote callable?

Comment: How can you pass a condition to a function? e.g. fun(L, F, >2)

Comment: Again, wrap it in a function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I would appreciate your solution because I do not see how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel. Just use something like this:

```
>>> l = [[0,1], [2,3,4,5], [6,7], [8,9],[10]]
>>> def all_true(iterable, f, condition):
...     return all(condition(f(e)) for e in iterable)
... 
>>> def cond(x): return x == 2
... 
>>> all_true(l, len, cond)
False
```

You can define a different function to check a different condition:

```
>>> def cond(x): return x >=  1
... 
>>> all_true(l, len, b)
True
>>>
```

And really, having your own function that does this seems like overkill. For example, to deal with your "complex condition" you could simply do something like:

```
>>> l = [[0,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,3,4]]
>>> all(len(sub) > 2 and sub[0] == 5 for sub in l)
False
>>> all(len(sub) > 1 and sub[0] == 0 for sub in l)
True
>>>
```

Comment: Close, but I do not want to have to define the condition separately each time

Comment: @SumNeuron Then set a default value? I don't see how you expect to be able to test different conditions without changing the condition...

Comment: @SumNeuron or use a `lambda` to define single-use anonymous functions.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is about a general function, i.e. multi-use

Comment: @SumNeuron You seem confused. You will always need to use either a pre-built condition or define your own.

Comment: That is not the case in every language. There should be a way to pass a condition as an argument

Comment: @SumNeuron for example? You are using condition in a very loose sense, I hope you realize.

Comment: Call it what you like, it is a condition, a test, evaluating an equivalence relation: either way I want to test a given condition (e.g. >) for all elements in a list L against a value (e.g. 2).

Comment: So what is an example of a language that works the way you want, perhaps it would be easier if you gave that.

Answer (score 1):

Python already has built-in the machinery you are trying to build. For example to check if all numbers in a list are even the code could be:

```
if all(x%2==0 for x in L):
    ...
```

if you want to check that all values are "truthy" the code is even simpler:

```
if all(L):
    ...
```

Note that in the first version the code is also "short-circuited", in other words the evaluation stops as soon as the result is known. In:

```
if all(price(x) > 100 for x in stocks):
    ...
```

the function price will be called until the first stock is found with a lower or equal price value. At that point the search will stop because the result is known to be `False`.

To check that all lengths are `2` in the list `L` the code is simply:

```
if all(len(x) == 2 for x in L):
    ...
```

i.e. more or less a literal translation of the request. No need to write a function for that.

If this kind of test is a "filter" that you want to pass as a parameter to another function then a `lambda` may turn out useful:

```
def search_DB(test):
    for record in database:
        if test(record):
            result.append(record)
            ...

search_DB(lambda rec: all(len(x) == 2 for x in rec.strings))
```

---

> I want a function that takes a list, a function, and a condition, and tells me if every element in the list matches the condition. i.e. foo(List, Len, >2)

In Python `>2` is written `lambda x : x>2`.

There is (unfortunately) no metaprogramming facility in Python that would allow to write just `>2` or things like `·>2` except using a string literal evaluation with `eval` and you don't want to do that. Even the standard Python library tried going down that path (see `namedtuple` implementation in `collections`) but it's really ugly.

I'm not saying that writing `>2` would be a good idea, but that it would be nice to have a way to do that in case it was a good idea. Unfortunately to have decent metaprogramming abilities you need a homoiconic language representing code as data and therefore you would be programming in Lisp or another meta-language, not Python (programming in Lisp would indeed be a good idea, but for reasons unknown to me that approach is still unpopular).

Given that, the function `foo` to be called like

```
foo(L, len, lambda x : x > 2)
```

is just

```
def foo(L, f=lambda x : x, condition=lambda x: x):
    return all(condition(f(x)) for x in L)
```

but no Python programmer would write such a function, because the original call to `foo` is actually **more code** and **less clear** than inlining it with:

```
all(len(x) > 2 for x in L)
```

and requires you to also learn about this thing `foo` (that does what `all` and a generator expression would do, just slower, with more code and more obfuscated).

Comment: That works but it isn't a callable function. I would have to type that out every time.  Ideally I would like to be able to give it the list, function, and condition and then run the equivalent `all(function(x) condition for x in list)`

Comment: yeah but I want it to work with any arbitrary functions applied to x in L and any arbitrary condition

Comment: I want a function that takes a list, a function, and a condition, and tells me if every element in the list matches the condition.  i.e. foo(List, Len, >2)

Comment: Ahhhh. He wants Lisp!

Comment: @SumNeuron: I've added the implementation of that function `foo`. Still is code that no Python programmer would write... calling it is more work than not having a function at all.

Comment: one would write `all(len(x) > 2 for x in L)` in a script sure, but if you are planning to call it with various tests, and various lists, then definition is practical and cleaner to read

Comment: @SumNeuron: probably cleanliness is in the eye of the beholder then.

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite the function so that instead of having to call foo(L, len, lambda x : x > 2), the lambda x is implied and I can just call foo(L, len, x > 2)

Comment: @SumNeuron: unfortunately no. `foo` would need to be a macro, not a function (last parameter is code). Python doesn't provide this kind of machinery. In Lisp it would be possible (not sure it would be a good idea even there, tho).

Comment: It would probably make sense to combine the function and the condition into a single function argument. Pass `lambda x: len(x) < 2` for instance. The default could be `bool`, which is a counterexample to your suggestion that "python doesn't have function meant for explicitly returning if something is True".

Comment: @Blckknght: it would even make more sense to combine the function the test and the iteration together ... with something we could call a "generator expression". Wait. It's already there. It's `all(len(x) < 2 for x in L)`!

Answer (score 0):

I think the ideal solution in this case may be:

```
def AllTrue(List, Test = lambda x:x):
  all(Test(x) for x in List)
```

This thereby allows complex queries like:

```
l = [[0, 1], [1, 2, 3], [2, 5]]

AllTrue(l, lambda x: len(x) > 2 and x[0] == 1)
```

---

To adhere to Juanpa's suggestion, here it is in python naming conventions and an extension of what I posted in the question now with the ability to handle simple conditions like x > value.

```
from operator import *
all_true(a_list, a_function, an_operator, a_value):
  a_map = map(a_function, a_list)
  return all( an_operator(m, a_value) for m in a_map)


l = [[0,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,3,4]]

all_true(l, len, gt, 2)
#True
```

Note: this works for single conditions, but not for complex conditions like

`len > 2 and element[0] == 5`

Comment: So your "ideal solution" just composes `all` and `map`, i.e. `AllTrue` is equivalent to `all(map(Test, List))` with the exception that the latter has a well-understood behaviour whereas `AllTrue` is unknown at best and misleading at worst. :-]

Comment: To be fair, your "ideal solution" no longer matches the requirements you gave in your initial question (it's not a ternary function), so I think Juanpa certainly should get some credit.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe yup :) I guess AllTrueQ would make it more apparent that the function returns a boolean answer the question if all the values in the list are true based on the function.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe true, I no longer include the function to apply and the condition separately, so different, but in the spirit of the question. I do think Juanpa and 6502 should get some credit too, as it was their attempts to answer my poorly worded question that got me to what I wanted

Comment: I don't think `allTrue` makes anything more apparent really. Note that `AllTrue(l, lambda x: len(x) > 2 and x[0] == 1)` is even longer than just `all(len(x) > 2 and x[0] == 1 for x in l)`, but the latter is understood by anybody with a solid knowledge of Python. To me, there does not be any extra value in coming up with a new name for this function.

Comment: The length comes from the fact there isn't a short hand for lambda x: as for the naming convention is just comes from ones programming backgrond